# PageViewController - disable bounce problem

Tags: ios, swift

I have a PageViewController and am currently trying to disable bounce. I've already found some threads about this problem, but the given solutions disable bounce to the wrong side.

I got 2 ViewControllers, namely `homeView` and `timelineView` - homeView is being displayed initially and is index 0. When this view is shown, bounce get deactivated to both sides and I can't swipe to the next controller.

Does anybody see the issue?

My code:

```
class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView")
            let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "timelineView")

            return [vc1, vc2]

    }()

    var currentPage: Int = 0

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(disableSwipe(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "disableSwipe"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enableSwipe(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "enableSwipe"), object: nil)

        for subview in self.view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = subview as? UIScrollView {
                scrollView.delegate = self
                break;
            }
        }

        if let secondViewController = viewControllerList.first as? HomeViewController {
            self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            ...
        }
    }

    ...

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print(currentPage, viewControllerList.count)
        if (currentPage == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < scrollView.bounds.size.width) {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0);
        } else if (currentPage == viewControllerList.count - 1 && scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.bounds.size.width) {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0);
        }
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        if (currentPage == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x <= scrollView.bounds.size.width) {
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0);
        } else if (currentPage == viewControllerList.count - 1 && scrollView.contentOffset.x >= scrollView.bounds.size.width) {
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0);
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else { return nil }

        currentPage = previousIndex
        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

        currentPage = nextIndex
        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you just don't want the page controller's `UIScrollView` to bounce at the end, right? In that case you should try to set `scrollView.bounces = false`. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces)

Comment: This disables swipe to both side. Doing so I'm not able to swipe in the direction of the next ViewController. All I want is to solely disable bounce to the empty side without any upcoming VC. Is there a way?

Comment: Yes that's odd. Your implementation works for me for though? Since the `UIPageViewController` class isn't particularly customisable maybe you should look into instead adding Child view controllers to your own scroll view.

Comment: I found out the problem - it was changing `currentPage`'s value inside of the functions of `pageViewController`. I had to move it into `viewDidAppear` inside of each ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem - it was changing `currentPage`'s value inside of the functions of `pageViewController`. I had to move it into `viewDidAppear` inside of each ViewController.